# How can you constrain a neural network layer to simply be a n-dimensional rotation layer?

Tags: neural-networks, linear-algebra

I'm looking to constrain one layer of my neural network to specifically find the **best** rotation of its input in order to satisfy an objective.  (My end goal, where $R$ is the rotation layer, is of the form $R^T ~f_{objective} \left(Rz \right)$  ).

I am looking to train this (+ other components) via gradient descent. If $z\in\mathbb{R}^2$, then I can just say
$R = \left[ \begin{matrix}
\cos \theta & -\sin \theta\\
\sin \theta & \cos \theta
\end{matrix} \right] $,
and have $\theta$ be a learnable parameter.

However, I am lost on how to actually set this up for an $d$-dimensional space (where $d$>10). I've tried looking at resources on how to make a $d$-dimensional rotation matrix and it gets heavy into Linear Algebra and is way over my head. It feels like this should be easier than it seems, so I feel like I'm overlooking something (like maybe $R$ should just be a usual linear layer without any non-linear activations).

Anyone have any ideas? I appreciate you, in advance : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have a set of $d$ nodes with linear activation and weights $b_{ij}$ for input $j$ to node $i$.  If you can impose the constraints $\sum_j b_{ij}^2=1$ and $\sum_{j} b_{ij}b_{kj}=0$ for $i\neq k$ then the mapping from input to output is multiplying by an orthonormal matrix.

The orthonormal matrices form two connected sets: the rotations (determinant =1) and the rotations with reflection (determinant=-1).  If you have a learning rate that isn't too high, your transformation won't be able to jump between these components, so if you start your weights off at rotation they'll stay a rotation.

This assumes you want rotations around the origin. To get rotations around some other point needs non-zero intercept (bias) terms chosen to move that point to the origin, rotate, then move it back.

Comment: I was thinking something along that line! Thank you : ) The question is how can we enforce the orthonormal constraint on a weight matrix? Maybe this is just an implementation detail, and we can have a regulation loss which penalizes and W which is not orthonormal. What do you think?

Comment: For future readers, QR decomposition can help with this (since Q is orthogonal) via having W be an unconstrained learnable matrix and solve W = QR, and then actually use Q as your orthonormal. 
https://pytorch.org/docs/1.9.0/generated/torch.linalg.qr.html

Comment: @SeanK That would be one way. I was hoping there was a computationally cheaper way to do it for matrices that are known to be of the form $Q+\epsilon A$ for small $\epsilon$, like you'd get after an update.

Answer (score 0):

The most computationally efficient representation of a rotation is as a series of $n$ [householder reflections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Householder_transformation). The concept is pretty simple: your rotation is parameterized by a series of $n$ arbitrary vectors  $v_1\dots v_n$ each with $n$ elements. To apply a corresponding rotation to an input $x$ vector, iterate through each of your $n$ parameter vectors $v_i$ and reflect $x$ through that vector

$x \leftarrow x - 2v_i\frac{x \cdot v_i}{v_i \cdot v_i}$

Alternatively, you can construct your entire rotation matrix explicitely from $R = \overset{n}{\underset{i=1}{\prod}}\left(I - 2 \frac{v_i \otimes v_i}{v_i \cdot v_i}\right)$

See [here](https://fhvilshoj.github.io/files/fast-orthogonal-parameterization-with-householder-matrices.pdf) for a publication on this. Autograd frameworks like pytorch, tensorflow, or jax will have no problem backpropagating through this transformation so you can optimize parameters $v$.